# Python3: make a chain call of functions

Tags: python-3.x

This question could be *senseless*, it's just interesting for me is it possible ot not.
In my code I had a lot of similar checks and calls like:

```
if self.command == self.CMD_HELP:
    help(self.id)
if self.command == self.CMD_FIND:
    find(self.id)
...
```

I found that in theory it could be done as:

```
self.COMMANDS = {
    'help': help,
    'find': find,
    ...
}

And execution:

self.COMMANDS[command](self.id)
```

It's fine if I will call one function.
But what if I need to call something like `first(second(arg))` is it possible?

**Update**:
Sorry, my initial description appeared not very clear.
All this stuff is about the refactoring of the current implementation:

```
if command == MessageSettings.MSG_GLOBAL_HELP:
    notify_help(guid)
if command == MessageSettings.MSG_GLOBAL_DISCORD:
    sv_async.submit_fast(sv_discord.notify_discord_help(guid))
if command == MessageSettings.MSG_GLOBAL_FIND:
    sv_async.submit_fast(sv_discord.notify_found_discord_users(guid, param))
... a lot of other 'ifs'
```

In the same time I have to support the list of the values to make the comparison:

```
class MessageSettings:
    MSG_GLOBAL_HELP = 'help'
    MSG_GLOBAL_DISCORD = 'discord'
    MSG_GLOBAL_FIND = 'find'
    ...
    MSG_VALUES = [
        MSG_GLOBAL_HELP,
        MSG_GLOBAL_DISCORD,
        MSG_GLOBAL_FIND,
        ...
    ]
```

In this case if I add new option I will have to modify 3 places: new field in the class, add it into the array, add comparison and execution of `if == value -> function`.
Since functions can receive different amount of parameters I can rewrite all functions to take an `array []` as a singe param.
I thought of using a dictionary with a `"key -> function"`.
My question was that I did not understand if that was possible to apply this approach in cases if multiple function calls.
Also I don't know and I am not sure if such approach worth it.
ps: in my 3rd case there are:

```
def submit_fast(task):
    future = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(task, loop_fast)

def notify_found_discord_users(will_replace_with_array):
    anything
```

Comment: You mean `self.COMMAND['foo'](self.COMMAND['bar'](self.id))`?

Comment: Can you clarify how `first(second(arg))` relates to the `help` and `find` functions in your example code? Are you asking how you could use a list of keys like `[self.CMD_HELP,  self.CMD_FIND]` and want to compose those functions? Or do you want to make the composed function a value in the dictionary (so you'd have `self.CMD_FIRST_SECOND: something` in the dictionary)?

Comment: There is a simpler way of doing this `getattr(self, command)(self.id)`, but command need to be a name of a method

Comment: I'm sorry that my first example was unclear. Added description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use lamda as in :

```
def help (n):
  return "help " + n + " "

def find (n):
  return "find " + n + " "

COMMANDS = {
    'help': help,
    'find': find,
    'other' : (lambda x: help(x) + find(x))
}

print (COMMANDS['other']("Joe"))
```

Comment: Thank you. I did not know about lambdas in python. There is always something new. In theory I could apply them to my needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean something like this,

```
def lower(x):
    return x.lower()

def upper(x):
    return x.upper()

a = "a string"
b = upper(lower(upper(a)))
```

Of course. 
the output of an inner function will be chained as the input of its outer function (as long as their parameters match).
It's the fundamental of any programming language.